# jslint-vim configuration

Tags: javascript, vim, jslint

I used the following plugin to install jslint for vim: https://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim.

I'm a bit confused as to how to configure this.

I see a list of options here http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options, but

1. in the jslint-vim plugin, where do I specify these options?
2. What is the option for removing indenting errors
3. What is the option to remove the "x variable was used before it was defined?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> in the jslint-vim plugin, where do I specify these options?

Create a *.jslintrc* in your home directory. The options are listed in a `/**/` comment block. There's an example in the documentation under **Usage**. Options set in your *.jslintrc* will apply to jslint generally, not just the vim plugin.

> What is the option for removing indenting errors

Try setting `white`: *tolerate messy whitespace*. But this will cause other issues to pass.

Put this in your *.jslintrc*:

```
/*jslint white: true */
```

> What is the option to remove the "x variable was used before it was defined?"

The option is named `undef`. Put this in your *.jslintrc*:

```
/*jslint undef: true */
```

Putting those two options together:

```
/*jslint white: true, undef: true */
```

Comment: Hey this is great and works thanks so much, but I keep getting these errors at the bottom of my screen frequently now as I'm editing a file "error in jslintrc, line 1, character 2: Expected '/*jslint' at column 1, not column 2." but it is at column1... the errors are frustrating as they take my cursor away from the active edit area and i need to click 'enter' to make them go away. know what this is about by any chance?

Comment: the above is preceded by this error: Error detected while processing function <SNR>55_JSLint:

Comment: @jdkealy what does your jslintrc look like. just paste the options line in a comment

Comment: JSLint is very particular about not having a space in the `/*jslint` part.  Your config should be `/*jslint white:true, undef:true */`.  It should *not* be `/* jslint white:true, undef:true */`.